# startFromScratch is removing the close (x) button of workbook

Tags: vba, excel, ribbon

For Excel I am using the attribute startFromScratch="True" to remove the ribbon tabs, but it is also removing the close button of the workbook (see picture). Is there a way to not remove it? I know that you can use startFromScratch and separately you can show a tab you want via VBA as this website explains: http://www.msofficegurus.com/post/Customizing-the-Ribbon-startFromScratch-and-Tab-visibility.aspx

Now, is it possible to add the close button again? I belive that there may be a similar code to show it via VBA.

[image: Before and after startFromScratch]

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="true">
<qat>
 <documentControls>
<control 
   idMso="FileSaveAs"
   screentip="SAVE AS..."
   supertip="Click here to save this file to another location."/>
<control 
   idMso="WindowSwitchWindowsMenuExcel"
   screentip="SWITCH EXCEL FILE"
   supertip="Click here to switch from this workbook to another open excel file."/>
<control 
   idMso="FilePrint"
   screentip="PRINT FILE"
   supertip="Click here to enable the print menu."/>
 </documentControls>
 </qat>
 </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**EDIT**

In the version of Excel that I'm using the following xml does not hide those buttons:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="true"></ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: Hi whytheq. Thanks for your answer, but unfortunatly this is not I am looking for :( I could use it to add a close workbook botton, but I'd like to show the default close workbook as show in the picture.

Comment: Did you test this code - it does not hide those buttons in my Excel. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. the xmlns address does not work for me because my office is 2010, but the rest of the code I tried and the close button still not showing :(